# Why is gcc-8.2 crashing when compiling my code

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 which comes with gcc version 5.4.0 as its default.

I built gcc-8.2 from source on the same machine and it is able to build a certain software project with no problems.

I then copied the actual compiler folder to another Linux machine running the same version of Ubuntu.

But then when I try to compile the same software project, I consistently get seg faults when gcc is compiling the code.  Strangely, it complains about a closing curly brace in one of the functions.

The code is written in C++.

The machine where it works has 32 GB of RAM whereas the machine where it is crashing (getting the seg faults) has 64 GB of RAM.

I ram memtest and verified that the RAM is the machine where it is faulting is good.

Does anybody know what could be going on and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You will need to try and isolate the fault to a minimally reproducible code snippet that causes GCC to crash, or in the worst case provide for the entire project source code or a link to a website hosting it. Noone will be able to tell you why it would crash without any details on your part -- it can be a gazillion of faults hidden inside GCC, and you uncovered but one, and faulty RAM doesn't have to have anything to do with it. Also, see if you can reproduce the crash with the online C++ compiler frontends: http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: It works on my dev box that has the exact same compiler - on some other Linux box, it seg faults.

Comment: That doesn't meaningfully narrow down the cause, unfortunately. What is your host operating system? The one running on physical hardware?

Comment: The error message I am seeing is happening in ggc-page.c:1474.  It is an internal compiler error.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04 in both cases.  On my dev box, I have a GUI.  On the box where it is seg faulting, there is no GUI.

Comment: Also, the box where it is crashing has double the RAM capacity (64 GB).

Comment: Both machines are intel core i7-6000 series (aka Skylake) CPU based systems.

Comment: The code that it is trying to compile uses template metaprogramming and variadic templates in a way that causes the compiler to use a TREMENDOUS amount of memory during the process of compiling the code.

Comment: Join me for a chat here, as we won't get far with commenting here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183150/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-53162197-why-is-gcc-8-2-crashing-when-compili

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit -a` on both systems?

Comment: too many characters for the comment box

Comment: i responded to the question with the info that you requested.  sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 0):

output of ulimit -a on good box:

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127133
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127133
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

output of ulimit -a on bad box:

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257100
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257100
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited